# How to Deny Access to anything except php files in Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, configuration-files

I want to deny access to anything except php files. I try with the following code in the httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/stf_1">
<Files *.*>
    Order Deny, Allow
    Deny from All
</Files>

<Files *.php>
    Order Allow, Deny
    Allow from All
</Files>

</Directory>
```

After the modification I tried to restart the server but doesnt respond. I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think the order of the directives is important. The way I am reading it is that you are first denying everything so the second directive doesn't fire.

Try

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/stf_1">
  <Files "*.php">
   Order Allow, Deny
   Allow from All
  </Files>

  <Files "*.*">
   Order Deny, Allow
   Deny from All
  </Files>
</Directory>
```